# How do I sort chronologically before writing the data VBA

Tags: vba, sorting, date

```
Sub retrieveFutureDates()
counter = 0
For i = 1 To 200
    If Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" And modDate(Cells(i, 4).Value) Then
            Cells(counter + 1, 6).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
            Cells(counter + 1, 7).Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value
            counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Currently I have this function that loops down one column of dates and applies the value of the date and the ticker of a stock if the date falls within 7 days(moddate). However, if in the list the dates are out of order, the sub will write 10/8 , 10/7, 10/6. Is there any way to write this in order or is there some way to make the worksheet/book sort automatically by date when the book is opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place a macro that will sort the range when the Workbook is open by placing the code in the Workbook_Open event in the ThisWorkbook object.

Comment: Will this be in the VBA editor or just macro recorded in excel?

Comment: In the VBA editor.  You never want to use the macro recorder for anything that will go into production.  It produces slow, inefficient code.  You can, however use the macro recorder to learn how a certain action can be performed by recording the action then viewing it in the VBE.